# Which currencies does Wizz Air use in-flight?

Tags: uk, air-travel, finland, wizz-air

Wizz Air is an Hungarian flight operator and I'll be flying with them from Finland to the United Kingdom.

If I'd like to pay with cash for in-flight services which currency should I bring?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [Wizz Air's Onboard Services](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/travel-information/onboard-services):

> We accept cash payments in different currencies.
>
> - Euros
> - British Pounds (notes only)
> - Hungarian Forint on Hungarian flights
> - Zloty on Polish flights
>
> All prices are quoted in Euros as the base currency. The prices in Pounds, Forint and Zloty are indicative prices subject to the exchange rate.
>
> Return change will be given in Euros unless the local currency is available.